# Complete page shifts to right side after loading in IE 7 and 8

Tags: html, css, drupal

It being two days and i am punching my head due to IE 7 and IE 8. When my web site (built in drupal) is loaded, it shifts to right side. Link is below :

http://goo.gl/GkMF6Z

I applied overflow hidden etc, but nothing is working and the page still moves to right side.

I need help to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

**Note: If someone give me details for a fix and it worked, i will offer a bounty of 50 points to correct answer after two days.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like.. problem is with your `doctype declaration`. Can you check that once?

**I got the issue**

Issue is with your `#menu #naviagtion_menu li ul` try making that `display:none` and everything will be fine. Menu has `position:absolute; left:-999em` which is creating space. Try playing with display properties instead left.

**Solution :**

```
#menu #naviagtion_menu li ul { left:auto; display:none;}
```

On hover of parent ul show this `#menu #naviagtion_menu li ul` with jquery/ javascript like you are doing with position left.

Comment: Can you please advice what doc type i should use?

Comment: Put <!DOCTYPE html>, before any other character in the document

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html> , not working. @Era by making class menu display:none, it will hide the top menu.

Comment: yeah, issue is with menu, i removed menu, and now the page is not shifting. Kindly be here with me, as i am playing with menu now :)

Comment: seems like working. Just let me check it and fix it, and then i will update my question according to your replies. You will also get your bribe ;)

Comment: Thanks era, your answer fixed the issues now. I will keep my promises.

Comment: got first bounty .. yooooooooooo

Comment: congrats. Another question. In IE, the fonts are not loaded. Can you help me in this regard? In all other browsers, the arabic fonts are loaded correctly, except IE :(

Comment: but i can easily see the fonts in evry IE. How you are showing this font?

Comment: The font is only not working in IE7 and IE 8 . I am using it as:  @font-face {
      font-family: "DroidSansArabicRegular";
       src: url("fonts/droidsansarabic.eot") format("embedded-opentype"), 
            url("fonts/droidsansarabic.woff") format("woff"), 
            url("fonts/droidsansarabic.ttf") format("truetype"), 
            url("fonts/droidsansarabic.svg#DroidSansArabicRegular") format("svg");
    }

Comment: Although, i dont have much knowledge about `font-face`, found few links which may help you http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax , http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/ . You can put another question to solve your issue. many other genius have worked on font-faces

Comment: thanks for the links. I fixed it. I am becoming a designer now :)

Comment: Hi Era, i hope you will be good. I got the same issue as above again in my other site, and now page moves a little right in IE when arabic language. In two days i found the blocks which are causing the issue, but using your above answer, i was not able to find the problem. Will you be able to help me out with this again? Thank you

Comment: Thanks Era, i found the issues finally. It was a div which was having negative margin left and i removed it. Now its fine :) .